# Codeigniter query showing num rows of 1 but row returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following query in CI 2.2:

```
$query = $this->db->select($this->identity_column . ', username, email, id, password, active, last_login')
    ->where($this->identity_column, $this->db->escape_str($identity))
    ->limit(1)
    ->get($this->tables['users']);
```

I then run this:

```
if ($query->num_rows() === 1)
{
    $user = $query->row();
}
```

num_rows() returns 1 so I get inside the if statement but $query->row() returns an empty array. I have run the produced SQL and it in fact grabs the correct row.

The query object looks like this:

```
object(CI_DB_pdo_result)#381 (8) { ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["conn_id"]=> object(PDO)#380 (0) { } ["result_id"]=> object(PDOStatement)#387 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(115) "SELECT username, username, email, id, password, active, last_login FROM users WHERE username = 'CORAIR4JK' LIMIT 1" } ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["row_data"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: What happens when you run the query in the command-line mysql client? What do you get for a result there?

Comment: I was getting back one row with the correct user. I dont know why the PDO driver wasn't working but the mysql driver is....but it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ain't no driver issue and do not go from PDO to OLD MySQL as PDO is much more secure, to get results you must use below,

```
if ($query->num_rows() === 1)
{
    $user = $query->result_array();
}
```

This will load all the database results into $user and will make it an array.

enjoy!!